# Bower version issue: SockJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, bower, sockjs

I want to get the latest SockJS via Bower and save this into my `bower.json` file.

According to the [GitHub sockjs-client page](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client), the latest version is `v1.0.3` (I see a tag for it).

However, I keep getting `v0.3.4`.  Here is the command I run:

```
> bower install sockjs --save
```

My results:

```
bower sockjs#*                  cached git://github.com/myguidingstar/bower-sockjs.git#0.3.4
bower sockjs#*                validate 0.3.4 against git://github.com/myguidingstar/bower-sockjs.git#*
bower sockjs#~0.3.4            install sockjs#0.3.4
```

I have tried a number of things, including:

```
> bower install https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client.git#v1.0.3 --save
```

And get an error:

```
bower sockjs#1.0.3          not-cached git://github.com/myguidingstar/bower-sockjs.git#1.0.3
bower sockjs#1.0.3             resolve git://github.com/myguidingstar/bower-sockjs.git#1.0.3
bower sockjs-client#v1.0.3      cached https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client.git#1.0.3
bower sockjs-client#v1.0.3    validate 1.0.3 against https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client.git#v1.0.3
bower sockjs#1.0.3        ENORESTARGET No tag found that was able to satisfy 1.0.3

Additional error details:
Available versions: 0.3.4
```

For some reason, no matter what I do, it keeps going back to `v0.3.4`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package you're looking for is `sockjs-client` not `socksjs`, therefore you should be doing

`bower install sockjs-client --save`

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I also had to delete `sockjs` folder from my `bower_components`.